# How to get recent n items average by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

There is a `Company` that has many `DailyDatum`. `DailyDatum` has `date` and `volume` columns.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :daily_data
end
```

I want to get a average of recent 10 `volumes`. By this code I got the average value.(I implemented `Array#mean` method)

```
company = Company.first
company.daily_data.order(date: :desc).limit(10).pluck(:volume).mean
```

And I thought it's more efficiant if I use `Postgresql` `AVG` function. but somehow `order` is ignored like this.

```
company.daily_data.order(date: :desc).limit(10).average(:volume)
   (15.7ms)  SELECT  AVG("daily_data"."volume") FROM "daily_data" WHERE "daily_data"."company_id" = $1 LIMIT 10  [["company_id", 1123]]
```

Can I use `limit`, `order`, `average` at the same time?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you order it by date or not, because it will be always 1 row.

Comment: Order desc by id it is a more efficient index as the number of records increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a sub-query for queries like that

```
select avg(volume) from
  (select volume from daily_data where company_id = 1 limit 10) as temp
```

Doing this in Rails will likely include the `find_by_sql` method. I however don't think you will notice any performance benefit from this, since you're only calculating 10 records.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use `find_by_sql` when I need to calculate much more records.